# Slow Grouping with MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

The code below is taking 30 seconds when grouping 80'000 posts by publish_target, type and status.

Are there any obvious ways to improve the load time?

```
            //by publish target
            $collection = $this->mongoDB->Post;
            $keys = array('publish_target' => true);
            $initial = array("count" => 0);
            $reduce = "function (obj, prev) { prev.count++; }";
            $result = $collection->group($keys, $initial, $reduce);
            foreach ($result['retval'] as $value) {
                $this->results['Post']['publish_target'][] = array('key' => $value['publish_target'], 'value' => $value['count']);
            }

        // by type
        $collection = $this->mongoDB->Post;
        $keys = array('type' => true);
        $initial = array("count" => 0);
        $reduce = "function (obj, prev) { prev.count++; }";
        $result = $collection->group($keys, $initial, $reduce);
        foreach ($result['retval'] as $value) {
            $this->results['Post']['type'][] = array('key' => $value['type'], 'value' => $value['count']);
        }

        // by status
        $collection = $this->mongoDB->Post;
        $keys = array('status' => true);
        $initial = array("count" => 0);
        $reduce = "function (obj, prev) { prev.count++; }";
        $result = $collection->group($keys, $initial, $reduce);
        foreach ($result['retval'] as $value) {
            $this->results['Post']['status'][] = array('key' => $value['status'], 'value' => $value['count']);
        }
```

---

fixed

```
            $ops = array(
                array(
                    '$group' => array(
                        '_id' => array($arrayKey => '$'.$arrayKey),
                        'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
                    )
                )
            );
            $retrieved = $collection->aggregate($ops);
```

Comment: Yes it will, the group function is really really really slow (it is basically a map reduce) not to mention deprecated in favour for the aggregation `$group` plus you are doing it three times, come on how fast do you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is not a single aggregation you are running, you are running three each based on output of previous one, and it's not clear why you would do that rather than just grouping by publish_target, type and status in a single aggregation.

Secondly, you are using group() function which is implemented via Javascript, rather than Aggregation Framework which runs natively on the server.   The only query/command you need is this:

```
db.post.aggregate({$group:{
          _id: { publish_target : "$publish_target" },
          count: {$sum : 1}
} );
```

You will now get those counts in a single pass on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm still learning how to manage mongo aggregations so I really appreciate the demo.

I tried converting that to PHP: $this->mongoDB->Post->aggregate(
                array('$group' =>
                    array('_id' =>
                        array('publish_target' => '$publish_target')
                    ),
                'count' => array(
                    '$sum' => 1)
                )
            );

but I get: Array ( [errmsg] => exception: wrong type for field (pipeline) 3 != 4 [code] => 13111 [ok] => 0 )

Comment: Or:             $posts = $this->mongoDB->Post->aggregate(
                array('$group' =>
                    array('_id' =>
                        array('publish_target' => '$publish_target')
                    )),
                array(
                'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
                )
            );

returns Array ( [errmsg] => Pipeline::run(): unrecognized pipeline op "count [ok] => 0 )

Comment: take a look at the example here: http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php I hope that clarifies the syntax issue